# Convert inches to cm in text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a large amount of product descriptions intended for American market, stored in MySQL text field like this:

**Dimensions: 13 3/4" x 2 3/4" x 10 1/4".**

Is there a way to convert them into cm? I guess there is no easy way but is there a way at all to have a query for this?

Comment: MySQL supports UDFs (User-defined functions) and Regular Expressions, so it's possible, sure.

Comment: I did a bit more research: MySQL only supports regex for matching, not capturing, and UDFs aren't like SQL Server's UDFs, so if you're looking for a SQL-only approach you might be SOL - unless you want pain with SUBSTRING.

Answer (score 0):

At application level you should be able to operate the conversion pretty easily, with simple arithmetic operations. Same thing might be doable within a query/stored procedure. I don't think there are any DBMS options to specifically carry on such a task... If you are trying to do a kind of "multicultural support" I'd try to look out for ways to make your application | DBMS aware of where the data is being accessed from, then operate the conversion programatically... hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use mysqldump utility to dump the database to text file.
2. Find and replace number (with calculation) in the text file. Use your favorite programming language to write a tiny tool to do it.
3. Import the edited text file back to your database.