# MySQL convert height format to centimeters

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to convert feet and inches to centimeters format

Format in my DB is:

> 4'6" (4 feet, 6 inches)

Formula for converting into centimeters

```
4*30.48 = 121.92 (convert feet to centimeters = multiply by 30.48)
6*2.54 = 15.24 (convert inches to centimeters   = multiply by 2.54)
So Result = 121.92 + 15.24 = 137.16 cm
```

eg:

Actual Table: inches

```
SELECT * FROM inches

id height
1  4'6"
2  4'7"
3  5'8"
4  5'9"
```

I expect the following result as centimeters when I do SQL query

```
id height
1  137.16
2  139.7
3  172.72
4  175.26
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you first convert it to inches first , then multiply by 2.54 ? i.e. `(4 x 12 + 6) x 2.54` ?

Comment: yes, that's fine. How to make a query ? please...

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837742/convert-inches-to-cm-in-text-in-mysql . In short, you should do it in application level , e.g. by PHP script .

Comment: @Raptor, thanks for you suggestton but, I really need to do it in SQL side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application side process will be better,

However,

```
    SELECT 
            (CAST(SUBSTR(height,1, LOCATE("'",height)-1) AS UNSIGNED) * 30.48) + 
            (CAST(SUBSTR(height,   LOCATE("'",height)+1) AS UNSIGNED) * 2.54 )   AS cm
    FROM 
            inches;
```

Comment: @Robby , no it wont, I checked it twice, Please try at your side !

Comment: @Asik, you're welcome ! However I would still prefer to do this at application side ! anyway, choice/preference/requirement is always yours !

Comment: @Raptor, you have a point ! yes, it will work for it,  only if the value would be  < 0'2" >

Answer (score 3):

Probably far easier to do on the application level, but if you really had to, you could do it in SQL like this, using the [`SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) and [`INSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) functions, and some basic math:

```
SET @height = '4''6"';
SELECT
    SUBSTR(@height, 1, INSTR(@height, '''') - 1) * 12 * 2.54 +
    SUBSTR(@height, INSTR(@height, '''') + 1, INSTR(@height, '"') - INSTR(@height, '''') - 1) * 2.54;

-- yields 137.16
```

Or, applied to your table structure:

```
SELECT id,
    SUBSTR(height, 1, INSTR(height, '''') - 1) * 12 * 2.54 +
    SUBSTR(height, INSTR(height, '''') + 1, INSTR(height, '"') - INSTR(height, '''') - 1) * 2.54 AS height
FROM inches;
```